# VB.NET How to save Program settings inside class module

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently building a program which requires numerous staff to use my program and the program is located on a shared drive on the network so all users can access the program. In my program I have a Database which I use to manage all the user accounts and other information. When you run the program for the first time ever on the network, it asks the administrator where to create the database. After the program creates the database, I save the connection string to a string variable in a class module within my program. However once I exit the program the value I set the to the string variable in the class gets erased. Is there a way to prevent the string from losing its value after closing the program ? I know I could do this via my.settings but I don't want to do it that way.

Comment: If there is only one value to save, it is hard to understand why you dont want to use Settings.  Otherwise recreate the wheel basically:  save it locally to a file.

Comment: No there is no way to stop the string losing its value when you close the program because the string doesn't exist when you close the program.  If you want a value to persist between sessions then the only way to do that is to write it somewhere external.  That's exactly what `My.Settings` does.  If you don't want to use `My.Settings` then you have to do that yourself.  When you start the application again, you have to read the data back in from the file.  That's exactly what `My.Settings` does.

Comment: @Plutonix, the one legitimate reason that I can think of is that `My.Settings` uses per-user values for read-write settings and to modify the read-only per-application settings you must be an admin user.

Comment: Why do you need to have the program on shared drive? Push it to user machines. Then you can use encrypted config section in separate file and your app.config can point to that file. Create another program on shared drive that will: 1 - download required latest assemblies,  2 - start your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own settings file using a binary serializer.

This method can be used to store an instance of your settings class to a file, which is not very human-readable. If human readability and editability is required, you could use an xml serializer instead. The settings file will reside in the application directory. You can control this with the variable `settingsFileName`.

Create a new console application and paste the code below. Run it a couple of times and note that the "connection string" is persisted through application close and open.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

Module Module1

    Private settingsFileName As String = "Settings.bin"
    Private mySettingsClass As SettingsClass

    Private Sub loadSettings()
        Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter()
        If File.Exists(settingsFileName) Then
            Using stream As New FileStream(settingsFileName, FileMode.Open)
                mySettingsClass = CType(formatter.Deserialize(stream), SettingsClass)
            End Using
        Else
            Using Stream As New FileStream(settingsFileName, FileMode.CreateNew)
                mySettingsClass = New SettingsClass()
                formatter.Serialize(Stream, mySettingsClass)
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub saveSettings()
        Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter()
        If File.Exists(settingsFileName) Then
            Using stream As New FileStream(settingsFileName, FileMode.Truncate)
                formatter.Serialize(stream, mySettingsClass)
            End Using
        Else
            Using stream As New FileStream(settingsFileName, FileMode.CreateNew)
                formatter.Serialize(stream, mySettingsClass)
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub

    <Serializable>
    Public Class SettingsClass
        Public Property ConnectionString As String = ""
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Loading settings...")
        loadSettings()
        Dim connectionString = mySettingsClass.ConnectionString
        Console.WriteLine("Connection string: ""{0}""", connectionString)
        Console.WriteLine("Enter new connection string...")
        mySettingsClass.ConnectionString = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Saving settings...")
        saveSettings()
        Console.WriteLine("Done!")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Add additional properties to `SettingsClass` which can be used elsewhere in your application.

Comment: there is a good reason not to use BinarySerializer for persistence objects - it changes version to version.

Comment: True, and maybe I should remove the last line of my answer. But if the settings class always just has a single string property it should be fine.

Comment: There are other binary serializers other than the BinaryFormatter which are not version specific.  Eitehr is overkill for one setting though.

Comment: This does answer the OP's question though.

Comment: Thank you this was just what I needed.